# How to remove tags except mail format container tags

Tags: php, regex, email, replace

It's difficult to describe my problem by words, I will try by giving an example:

```
str = '<p>lorem ipsum <xyz@abc.com> donor sit <br></p>';
```

I need to remove all tags except **`<xyz@abc.com>`**

How can we do in javascript and also PHP?

My PHP solution :

```
class test {
    public function keepMailAddresses($text){
       $callBack = array($this,'_keepMailAddresses');
       return preg_replace_callback('/(<)([^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]*([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4})(>)/i', $callBack, $text);        
    }

    private function _keepMailAddresses($matches){
       return '&lt;'.$matches[2].'&gt;';
    }

}

$obj = new test();
echo $obj->keepMailAddresses('<p>lorem ipsum <xyz@abc.com> donor sit <br></p>');
```

Comment: This is invalid markup. The `<>` around the email address should be `&gt;` and `&lt;` or, if this is XHTML, the P text should be a CDATA section. The way it is now the email is creating an invalid element.

Comment: @Gordon I totaly agree with you, I need to convert < and > to &gt; and &lt; only if it's an email address, other case tags should be striped.

Comment: @WebolizeR No, you should have inserted the angle brackets as entities already…

Comment: The case is very very complicated, because of this, I need to do such a thing, 10 year old code, bad logic etc.

Comment: your php function work gr8, what is your problem now? to do the same in javascript?

Comment: yes, need the JS version also

Answer (score 1):

ok my solution is little bit weird, but will do the trick :D

```
$pagecode = '<p>lorem ipsum <xyz@abc.com> donor <abc_def.xyz@abc.com> sit <abc_def.xyz@abc.abc.com><br></p>';

// this will check if it's a real email but you don't need it
/*$allowed = preg_match_all("/\<+([_a-z0-9-]+)(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@([a-z0-9-]+)(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})+\>/i", $pagecode, $matches);*/

$allowed = preg_match_all("/\<([_a-z0-9-\.]+)@([_a-z0-9-\.]+)\>/i", $pagecode, $matches);

$allowed = implode(" ", $matches[0]);
$output = strip_tags($pagecode, $allowed);
echo htmlentities($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

use below in headers section

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

and put like this

```
str = '<p>lorem ipsum "<xyz@abc.com>" donor sit <br></p>';
```